How to resolve "X-Frame-Options: deny" issue during silent token refresh with iframe?
I am using silent refresh to renew the token in my application, which involves loading an iframe pointing to the Identity Server's endpoint. However, when the iframe tries to load the URL https://localhost:9443/, I get the following error in the browser console:
Refused to display 'https://localhost:9443/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Here is the setup I'm working with:
Identity Server 7.0.0: WSO2 IS running on https://localhost:9443/
Frontend Framework: Angular 18 with angular-oauth2-oidc package for authentication
Silent Refresh: Using the library's built-in silentRefresh() method
This is the config :
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
   issuer: 'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token',
   redirectUri: window.location.origin,
   clientId: '6wgRGIKSFcB61WSDSsf0n1fysGIa',
   dummyClientSecret : "fNksWZHkxXQMv14GZ9oVYJaYyOrEJchcFuPsurYxGloa",
   strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
   responseType: 'code',
   scope: 'openid profile roles',
   showDebugInformation: true,
   silentRefreshRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-refresh.html',
   useSilentRefresh: true,
   sessionChecksEnabled: true,
   timeoutFactor: 0.75,
   clearHashAfterLogin: true,
   logoutUrl: 'https://localhost:9443/oidc/logout',
   skipIssuerCheck: true,
};

the silent-refresh.html
<html>
   <body>
   <script>
      parent.postMessage(location.hash, location.origin);
   </script>
   </body>
</html>

the service
this
    .oauthService
    .silentRefresh()
    .then(info => console.debug('refresh ok', info))
    .catch(err => console.error('refresh error', err));


Identity Server is responding with that header set to secure it's login.   (Don't put the login in the frame... or use another flow.. implicit flow is not really recommended... use authorization code flow:  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#interactive-clients )  You could remove that header, but it would allow other sites to frame it.

@browsermator You're right but OP is asking about WSO2 IS not the .NET IdentityServer4

The HTTP X-Frame-Options response header can be used to indicate whether a browser should be allowed to render a page in a frame, iframe, embed or object. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.
In WSO2 IS, the X-Frame-Options header is set to DENY by default based on the security best practices. For example, you can change the X-Frame-Options header value to SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW-FROM for the oauth2 webapp by updating the antiClickJackingOption parameter in the <IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/web.xml file. This is further explained in the documentation:
<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

For the accountrecoveryendpoint and authenticationendpoint web applications, direct modification of the web.xml file to enable HSTS is not supported. Instead, configure the settings through the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml file. Example configurations are as follows:
For accountrecoveryendpoint:
[[accountrecoveryendpoint.tomcat.http_header_security_filter.parameters]]
name = "param-name"
value = "param-value"

For authenticationendpoint:
[[authenticationendpoint.tomcat.http_header_security_filter.parameters]]
name = "param-name"
value = "param-value"

